# "for /f" not working in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

This is my first question on stack overflow.

I'm having some trouble with the `for /f` command in batch. What I'm trying to do is this:

```
for /f "skip=3 tokens=1" %%G in ('arp -a') do (echo %%G)
```

The command executes fine from command prompt (using `%G` instead of `%%G`), but when I try to run it in a batch file, it just outputs a blank line. I have to use CTRL+C to exit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't replicate your results. You didn't happen to call it arp.bat, did you? (because that will break everything)

Comment: Oops, I did. I can't believe I messed that up, Jeez. Thank you.